# Private channels in node.js and redis. How to?

Tags: node.js, redis, private, channel

I wrote the simple script (app.js) to subscribe redis' channel

```
var app = require('express').createServer()
, io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

var redis = require("redis");

app.listen(8080);

////////////// Dev environment; replace by PERL in production use.
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
//////////////

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.subscribe = redis.createClient();
    socket.subscribe.subscribe('chat');

    socket.subscribe.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        socket.send(message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        socket.subscribe.quit();
    });

    socket.on('close', function() {
        socket.subscribe.quit();
    });
});
```

Now, I want to make possible to subscribe to private channel for each user.

I tried to pass extra data via socket.io.connect like this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080', {'PRIVATE_ROOM_HASH': 'secret_hash'});
  socket.on('message', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
</script>
```

and then in app.js

```
...
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket, args) {
    socket.subscribe = redis.createClient();
    socket.subscribe.subscribe(args.PRIVATE_ROOM_HASH);

    socket.subscribe.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        socket.send(message);
    });
```

but it does not work.

Any ideas how to resolve private rooms' problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can pass extra arguments to the socket.io connect command and then get them in the server. If I'm wrong someone correct me. I can't find this anywhere in the socket.io documentation.

Anyway, socket.io has built in support for rooms. On the client side, you would for example send a `join` event to the server with the name of the room

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
socket.on('connect', function() {
  socket.emit('join', 'secret_hash');
});

socket.on('message', function(msg) {
  // got a messae!
});
```

And on the server, you would use the rooms feature.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('join', function(room) {
    socket.join(room);
    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
      socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('message', msg);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks DeaDEnD! I think this is a good solution. Anyway, I will not use socket.join and socket.broadcast because I'm using Redis also in others parts of application (eg. in Perl's code), so I will stay with redis.createClient()

Comment: Do you have an example code for this, I built a laravel app with redis and socket and I stuck on creating these private channels

Answer (score 0):

No need to do that, since you'll be duplicating functionality. With Socket.IO you can make the client join rooms, like described on their github page:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.join('justin bieber fans');
  socket.broadcast.to('justin bieber fans').emit('new fan');
  io.sockets.in('rammstein fans').emit('new non-fan');
});
```

Also if you'd like real auth, the best would be with sessions, I recommend you read the article about [Express, Socket.IO and sessions](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/).